# Black body heat to current conversion

Tags: low-power, power-engineering

I have learnt about Seebeck effect and peltier effect in college physics, but it was more of  theory than hands on numbers and practicals.

Now is there a commercial or DIY module that can produce some current from a black body heated from sunlight.

Are there any graphs, and numbers you can provide. Any research papers. I am not looking for ways to convert heat to current using rotary generators. Rather I need a direct conversion, like a solar panel converts light to current. Is there a material that can convert heat from a surface to potential difference and current.

I need enough power to make a mobile phone charger out of its output.

The gradient I might have is around 70 to 80°C at the hot junction and 20 to 25 °C at the cold junction. My plan is to have a hot junction with a large surface area, with less volume (like a large sheet). And a dense cold junction with far less surface area. Has anyone tried this as a home project, Any personal experience in trying out this principle would be much helpful.

Comment: The challenge you will face is that this only works for temperature *differences*, not for *absolute* temperatures. So you'll need to cool down one side of the Peltier while heating up the other side. Heating one side in the sun is the easy part.

Comment: Did you try using google? "Seebeck Generator"

Comment: Yes, that's what I intent to ask. I couldn't find any commercially available panels. And has any of you tried this. At least with a hot junction and a junction at room temperature. And exact practical considerations while trying this out.

Comment: It exists, in soviet union there were plenty of radio beacons that used plutonium core as a heat source and lots of thermocouples to produce elecricity form heat. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator

Comment: There's the "Biolite stove" that does this. Because the process isn't very efficient and depends on the heat flow through the panel, they use a fire at several hundred C on one side and a fan on the other. If you're heating in the sun, conventional PV is a much better idea.